# Oracle SQL to Excel using VBA -Dumb data in different worksheet in the same workbook

Tags: oracle, vba, excel

I have a report to generate where I have a command button in the sheet1. I've written some VB code to create a new excel workbook everytime the button is clicked and then dump the SQL query results there.
However what my manager wants is, the first time I click the button, the data should be dumped by opening a new workbook but the consecutive clicks should dump the data in the same workbook but new sheet. This should happen till I close the excel sheet with the command button.

Again the next time I open this excel with commandbutton, the data should be dumped in a new workbook on the 1st click but the for the consecutive clicks , the data should be exported to the new worksheet.
Please find my code here:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Call Ora_connection
   ThisWorkbook.Activate

End Sub

Public Sub Ora_connection()

Dim oconn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim xla As New Excel.Application
Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook
Dim xlws As Excel.Worksheet

strSQL = ' SQL SELECT here1

Set oconn = New ADODB.Connection
oconn.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=" & Sheet1.TextBox3.Text & ";User Id=" & Sheet1.TextBox4.Text & ";Password=" & Sheet1.TextBox5.Text & ";"

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Open the recordset
rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.Open strSQL, oconn, adOpenStatic

'open new workbook and export the data
Set xla = New Excel.Application
    xla.Visible = True
Set xlw = xla.Workbooks.Add
    xlw.Activate
Set xlws = xlw.ActiveSheet

'to copy the header of the table   
With xlws.Range("A2")
For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        xlws.Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next i
        '.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs

End With
On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close

oconn.Close
If Not rs Is Nothing Then Set rs = Nothing
If Not oconn Is Nothing Then Set oconn = Nothing
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

Comment: For the moment, you don't save your file automaticly, so it's harder to get a hold again on a file when you reuse your button. **2 major things to add** :

**save the file** in a known location+name,
**add a sheet** (set it to veryhidden with code) to save paramaters :
-boolean if the file is already created (with an added if in your code to create workbook or add sheet),
filename with location, and maybe other things...

With that you should be able to make what's ask!

Comment: I could save the file as you said which is a safe option and correct solution however I'm really not sure which drive these ppl whose use this tool will have save permissions. So I've left that option open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make the Workbook variable static by changing `Dim xlw As New Excel.Workbook` to the statement `Static xlw As Workbook` (or make it a module level private variable). Then check if xlw was already created.

```
Static xlw As Workbook
Dim xlws As Worksheet
If xlw Is Nothing Then 'New instance'
    Set xlw = Workbooks.Add
    Set xlws = xlw.ActiveSheet
Else 'Workbook instance present'
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlws = xlw.Worksheets.Add
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then 'The target of xlw no longer references a valid object.'
        Set xlw = Workbooks.Add
        Set xlws = xlw.ActiveSheet
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 'Or your error handler'
End If
```

- If you're already in Excel VBA you don't need to create the application with `New Excel.Application` or use the prefix of Application or Excel.
- In case the target of the instance of the Workbook is no longer valid (the file was closed), an Automation Error will occur. To handle this the only option is to trap the error and handle it, hence the `On Error` and `Err.Number` check. In this case a new Workbook will be created. (Change the error handling to suit your solution).
- As R3uK mentioned, a safer solution would be to save the file automatically, look for it in open files, and open it if necessary.

Comment: Thank you for responding ! I will surely try this and let you know.